# Is there a way to track derivatives of powerpoint presentations?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2013

Say we have the following scenario: We have one master powerpoint presentation with all the slides, numbers, content, etc.

And I would like to create 2 presentation from it. One that has a few extra slides and another that has a few changed slides but largely the same.

Is there a way to track all three of these versions so that only one master slide is updated and the other presentations update automatically?

The solution does not have to be part of PowerPoint. Could be some 3rd party software too.

Also asked on Quora at http://qr.ae/NW416

Comment: There's nothing like this built into PPT; some (probably rather expensive) third party software might be able to do at least part of what you're after, but I don't know of anything offhand that'd help.

Comment: Amazes me that nobody has needed one yet!

Comment: Lots of people/companies need something like this.  Problem is that every one of them has different needs; one solution never fits all (and usually not any two customers).  I've either written parts of software like this or discussed it with any number of clients.

Comment: Why not use a custom show?  You can input all the slides into the master presentation and the select which slides to show for each of the other two shows.